# What can I use aside from .north, .south, .east, .west, .center in a GUI in java?

Tags: java

```
   add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(bread, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(sandwiches, BorderLayout.EAST);
  add(drinks, BorderLayout.WEST);
  add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I currently have a GUI and have used these 5 location allocation. Is there another one I can use if I want to add another panel on the right side?

Comment: You can put a panel in EAST with its own layout and put as many things as you like in it.

Comment: You can combine various [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: _"Is there another one I can use if I want to add another panel on the right side"_  - You can nest panels with different layout managers.

Comment: @khelwood Hi, thanks for the reply. I looked a bit more into it with the links provided by other people but still have a bit of trouble understanding it. With my code above, what would I be modifying to create a panel with it's own layout?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Hi, thanks for the reply. I looked a bit more into it with the links provided by other people but still have a bit of trouble understanding it. With my code above, what would I be modifying to create a panel with it's own layout?

Comment: Indicate your GUI framework. If Swing, say so.

Comment: Update your question with an ascii diagram showing how you want your components displayed. You need to logically group components together in a panel and then logically group panels. Each panel should use the appropriate layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add another panel on the right side?

So you create another child JPanel with the appropriate layout manager:

```
JPanel east = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
east.add(sandwiches, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

JPanel anotherPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
anotherPanel.add( new JButton("Button1") );
anotherPanel.add( new JButton("Button2") );

east.add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

//add(sandwiches, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

So the "east" panel becomes a nested panel that contains two other panels.